# droid: How can I validate EditText input?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have an edittext , I just want to show a message when an english character or word is inserted via the keyboard , what shall I do?

Comment: Use TextWatcher (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) and Validation both (http://blog.donnfelker.com/2011/11/23/android-validation-with-edittext/).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432083/how-to-use-edittext-ontextchanged-event-when-i-press-the-number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do like this -

```
((EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_testo)).addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
        int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeToast(activity.this, s.toString(), Toast.Long).show();
}
});
```

Have a look at [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

Answer (score 0):

Use TextWatcher to watch the text in the EditText and whenever an English character or word is detected in "onTextChanged" mehod of TextWatcher you can show a message.

An Example is as follows

```
TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // or here
            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // Check for English Character or word here and show message
        };

        // Set listener on the original text field
        itemText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

    }
```

Hope it helps!!!