# Detecting an onTextChanged event in dot42

Tags: android, dot42

I want an ediText field in my app to respond to onTextChange events so a method is called when the text changes. I am using dot42 to make the app but could only find tutorials available in Java.

Comment: did you try anything , at least [Google](http://www.google.com)

Comment: yes i did. but didn't help. if know how to do it please share.

Comment: [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432083/how-to-use-edittext-ontextchanged-event-when-i-press-the-number) , and [link2](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=ontextchange+event+in+android&oq=ontextchange+event+in+android&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.6387j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: please read the question. I want to do it in dot42 not by java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be a minimal implementation. I hope it helps you see a pattern in the difference between Java and C# - it is really trivial.

```
   [Activity]
   public class MainActivity : Activity, Android.Text.ITextWatcher
   {
      protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstance)
      {
         base.OnCreate(savedInstance);
         SetContentView(R.Layouts.MainLayout);

         EditText editText = FindViewById<EditText>(R.Ids.status);
         editText.AddTextChangedListener(this);
      }

      public void AfterTextChanged(Android.Text.IEditable s)
      {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
      }

      public void BeforeTextChanged(Java.Lang.ICharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
      {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
      }

      public void OnTextChanged(Java.Lang.ICharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
      {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
      }
   }
```

The interface implementation is generated by Visual Studio.

Comment: If it were possible I would give you 1,000 points...  I'm from hours around this issue

Answer (score 1):

In Java you'd do it by implementing a TextWatcher interface.
[Dot42 documentation](http://docs.dot42.com/Reference/M.Android.Widget.TextView.AddTextChangedListener%28Android.Text.ITextWatcher%29) says that

```
AddTextChangedListener(ITextWatcher watcher)

Adds a TextWatcher to the list of those whose methods are called whenever this TextView's text changes.`
```

So implement [ITextWatcher](http://docs.dot42.com/Reference/T.Android.Text.ITextWatcher), do something in `AfterTextChanged` and you're OK.

Comment: I read the documentation but didn't help. Please share sample code if you have .

Comment: I don't have any sample code. Did you try to do as I suggested? Did you call myTextView.AddTextChangedListener with the custom ITextWatcher?