# How to automatically add the result to a textbox, without pressing a button in Android

Tags: android

In my android project I am using three text boxes. They are `txtPurchase` , `txtSales`, and `txtProfit`. When I enter the value 5000 in `txtpurchase` and 6000 in `txtsal` I want to then display the value of 1000 in `txtprofit` without a button click. Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Comment: you can use onTextchanged method of editText.see the reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432083/how-to-use-edittext-ontextchanged-event-when-i-press-the-number

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with an `OnTextChanged` listener.

```
txtSales.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.length() > 0 && txtPurchase.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                // logic here to do the math
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```