# Null pointer exception before TextChanged in android

Tags: android, android-textwatcher

It's giving me null pointer exception i have initialized added textwatcher but still i am having this exception. Am I forgetting some thing.
Any Help is Appreciated.

```
    EditText editText = (EditText) dialogList.findViewById(R.id.search);
editText.addTextChangedListener(mSearchTw);

mSearchTw = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {
        pokeAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
};
```

Comment: Why you do like this, you can do simply like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432083/how-to-use-edittext-ontextchanged-event-when-i-press-the-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @user8 gives the answer you can pass the null object of class.You just change like this

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        TextWatcher mSearchTw  = new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {
                pokeAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        };

        editText.addTextChangedListener(mSearchTw);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not initiated properly ,

You can check using editText.getText().toString()
If through error then it means not initiate properly

Comment: Thanks i accepted the answer already but i will vote up. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Of course, it will give you Null Pointer, you basically add a `null` object at the following line

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(mSearchTw);
```

You add it before initializing it.

To fix, just move it after the initiation, i.e. after `mSearchTw = new TextWatcher() {...};`

That is because those statements are executed [sequentially](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/144481/what-is-sequential-code-execution).

Comment: Thanks it help me out :)